# Talned - How to add a THashInput to a TMap - Talend

Tags: talend

I am new to using Talend.

1. The first table is fed into tHashOutput1. This part works fine.
2. The tHashOutput1 is fed into tHashOut2 and tHashOutput3.
3. From tMap_3 is fed from user . When i try to feed tHashInput3 into the tMap i am not allowed to do this. What is wrong with this.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by not allowed ?  Whats the error message ? and where is your output from tMap3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `tHashInput3`have the schema of `tHashOutput1`, as you can see there is a small yellow warning on the `tHashInput3` but it not exist on `tHashInput2`. Also, there is no output from the `tMap3` to see if it works.